# Spring MVC, resources mapping failure in file upload / download app

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have an upload form, what I would like to achieve is an app, where uploaded files will be accessible through static links from the directory I save them into.

I have resources defined in servlet-context.xml as follows:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/files/**" location="/files/" />
```

But when I try to save files there with following code:

```
public void saveFile() throws IOException
{
    String path = File.separator + "files" + File.separator + filedata.getOriginalFilename();
    File dest = new File(path);

    filedata.transferTo(dest);
}
```

I get the error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \files\colour-palette.png (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

file is just a random one I use for testing.

This is how my webapp dir looks:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBx3E.jpg

Can anyone help me? I can post more code if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure your file is automatically created:

```
  public void saveFile() throws IOException
    {
        String path = File.separator + "files" + File.separator + filedata.getOriginalFilename();
        File dest = new File(path);
        dest.createNewFile();

        filedata.transferTo(dest);
    }
```

Comment: I think it is, I've seen it done this way in numerous tutorials. And anyway the files folder doesnt seem to be mapped correctly since even when I put something there manually I cant access it.

Comment: Did you try with an absolute path (with getServletContext().getRealPath("/")) ?